# How do I trace all request in IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003 SP2?

Tags: iis-6, trace

I found this site from MS:

> [Tracing Requests (IIS 6.0) - Microsoft TechNet](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5f5bd256-7d1f-4239-9a7f-8eea4072fcb3.mspx?mfr=true)

I set it up on my server as per the article and then used this to try and generate the report, but it keeps stating that `RequestID` cannot be found

My website seems to slow down during the day and all SQL inserts start taking 20 seconds to complete. I created an app which just flooded the SQL database with the inserts and those seem to work and used Empirix as well to flood the db.

Now I want to see the request in the worker process and why they seem to take long, but MS has left me abandoned...any other ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to trace the web requests, it might be easier to just run a SQL Profiler trace on your site when it starts getting slow.

Comment: david, that is running as well. I executed the sp in ? a few thousand times and it seems to work well when called froma c# test project. But when same library is called by the web project, the site slows down at diff times of the day. IIS logs keep showing Connection_Dropped